# Simple Pivot in R for two columns

Tags: r, pivot

Have tried reshape/melt and cast and could get the output what I need.

Just have to pivot/denormalize the data. I need a list of UPCs for a given RANK so I can do some arules on the output data. Any inputs are really appreciated.

Loaded my CSV file into a data frame.

```
md1 <- read.csv("sltrndtlfew.csv")[,2:3]
> md1

RNK          UPC
1  152221 725942843866
2  152221 882486415420
3  152221 723764327359
4  152221 882486419664
5  124578 884884731010
............
............
```

## Input  data is

```
RNK          UPC
152221 725942843866
152221 882486415420
152221 723764327359
152221 882486419664
124578 884884731010 <-
152221 886127223733
152221 732999083107
152221 732999090211
152221 732999083114
152221 883810901558
152221 732998067597
124578 634859192779  <-
152221 725942807578
152221 737445543587
152221 883810941127
124578 733004256219  <- 

263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
263945  91709433725
```

## Output needed is:

```
152221  725942843866,882486415420,723764327359....
124578  884884731010,634859192779, 733004256219  
263945  91709433725, 91709433725.....
```

Comment: You say you tried melting/casting - can you add the code you tried that didn't work?

Comment: Originally my dataset had many columns and I tried melt and cast. The output of the melt wasnt something I wanted, so I managed to remove other columns and bring only the 2 columns I am interested in on the database. My input data already looks like a melt'ed output and I ran the below cast on it -

Comment: > dcast(RNK,~UPC)
Error in parse(text = x)[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
>

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this:

```
library(dplyr)

results <- md1 %>%
  group_by(RNK) %>%
  summarise(listing = toString(UPC))

as.data.frame(results)
```

Comment: Not sure if that really works after I installed the dply package -

Comment: > results <- md1 %>%
+     group_by(RNK) %>%
+     summarise(listing = toString(UPC))
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: > results <- md1 %>%
    group_by(RNK) %>%
    summarise(listing = toString(UPC))
Error: could not find function "%>%"

Comment: Thanks Miha. It was a typo. But again i could only install "plyr" and couldnt install "dplyr" on the R version I am on.

Comment: install.packages("dplyr")    Warning: unable to access index for repository https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib
Warning message:
package ‘dplyr’ is not available (for R version 3.2.2)

Comment: Alright this is accomplished using aggregate function -                               x<- aggregate(cbind(UPC)~RNK,md2,FUN=function(x)paste(x,collapse=","))